# How to create a header like a standard library header, so that program can be compiled without linking all object files of functions in the header?

Tags: c++, header-files

Am trying to create a header file which can be included like 
`#include "sort.h "`
and the program in which the header is included can be compiled normally
`g++ main.cpp`
without having to link every single object file of functions in the header with the main.

```
g++ -c main.cpp insertion_sort.cpp merge_sort.cpp


g++ main.o merge_sort.o insertion_sort.o
```

so do I have to **link every single object file for every single function in the header.** or is their another way?
header file:

```
//sort.h file
#ifndef sort_h
#define sort_h

    void insertion_sort(int *a,int n);
    void merge_sort(int *a,int n);

    //I want to include more functions

    #endif
```

How to use my header like a normal header like cmath or stdlib.h?

Comment: System headers are also linked, you just don't see it. AFAIK, there's no way to avoid that, unless you put source code in the header file, which is not recommended. You could use some building system like CMake to help yourself managing your project.

Comment: Also, typical solution is to have one .cpp file corresponding to one .h file, rather than one file per function. Is there any particular reason to split them here?

Comment: You're stuck. The other objects need to get linked in somehow, be it individually or as part of a library. This is one of the things a decent build script or IDE handles for you. Take a look at tools like cmake.

Comment: One other unmentioned option is to template your functions/classes in your headers. Then, you don't need to link to any file; simply including the headers should be enough.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen _"System headers are also linked..."_ I wouldn't use such phrasing. Headers are included into sources by a preprocessor to from translation units, which are then compiled. Linked are corresponding libraries / object files of C / C++ Standard Library implementations.

Comment: @eozd how??can you explain please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write template functions entirely composed of header files. Then, you don't need any .cpp files and don't need to link to object files. Although this is not a direct solution to the asked question, it is a way of "not linking every single object file for every function".

### Putting All Together

If we give an example, you may try changing your sort.h file as follows

```
//sort.h file
#ifndef sort_h
#define sort_h

    template <typename T>
    void insertion_sort(T* a,int n) {
        // insertion sort implementation goes here
    }

    template <typename T>
    void merge_sort(T* a,int n) {
        // merge sort implementation goes here
    }

#endif
```

When you write your sorting routines as template functions here, your function must be generic enough to accomodate for generic T types. In general, for sorting routines, T must be less-than comparable.

### Separate Interface and Implementation

If you don't like to put documentation, interface and implementation all in one place, you may declare the function first together with its documentation. Then, you may define it below or possibly in some other file. So, the following is also possible:

```
//sort.h file
#ifndef sort_h
#define sort_h

    /**
     *  Function documentation
     */
    template <typename T>
    void insertion_sort(T* a,int n);

    /**
     *  Function documentation
     */
    template <typename T>
    void merge_sort(T* a,int n);


#include "insertion_sort.h"
#include "merge_sort.h"
#endif
```

---

```
//insertion_sort.h file
#ifndef insertion_sort_h
#define insertion_sort_h

    template <typename T>
    void insertion_sort(T* a, int n) {
        // insertion sort implementation goes here
    }

#endif
```

---

```
//merge_sort.h file
#ifndef merge_sort_h
#define merge_sort_h

    template <typename T>
    void merge_sort(T* a, int n) {
        // merge sort implementation goes here
    }

#endif
```

Some people like to call template header implementation files **.tpp** files. This depends on your preference.

### Using From main.cpp

You can use the first or the second options from main.cpp as follows:

```
//main.cpp
#include "sort.h"
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec_int;
    // fill vector

    insertion_sort(&vec_int[0], vec_int.size());

    std::vector<double> vec_double;
    // fill vector

    merge_sort(&vec_double[0], vec_double.size());
}
```

### Compiling

Since we didn't use any cpp files, now compiling main.cpp should be as simple as

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -g main.cpp
```

assuming that main.cpp and our header files are in the same directory. If header files are in some directory named include, then we compile with

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -Iinclude main.cpp
```

Comment: Better to compile with at least `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch I have included them. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @eozd is it kind of mandatory to use templates, what if I only need to sort intergers or double?? thanks for the answer

Comment: There may be other ways of achieving what you want, but I don't know them. If you only want to use int or doubles, you may make sure that T is int or double at compile time using [static_assert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) and [std::is_same](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same). However, I am not sure why you would want to restrict the types to int or double for sorting functions.

Comment: @Adwaith R Krishna If this post answered your question, consider accepting it.

Comment: You don't have to make the functions templates you can simply mark them `inline`.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be under the impression that things you get from standard library headers don't have corresponding object files/library files that need to be linked in. This is wrong.

The standard library *is* linked to your application, it's just that the compiler does it automatically for you. You don't have to tell it manually to do so.

Your application also needs the standard library available in order to *run*. This is why you have to install the Microsoft redistributables on a machine where you want to run a program built with Visual Studio for example. Other compilers have similar requirements that you need to distribute their run-time libraries along with your application.

In short; the standard library is no different from other libraries, except for the fact that the compiler links it in for you behind the scenes.